# Doxygen assign multiple functions to class

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to document C interface of my library with doxygen. All functions are grouped within a virtual classes and the assigned with operator [\memberof](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdmemberof). Since there are a lot of functions, I would like to assign multiple functions with group operator @{.

```
/**
* \class Base
*/

/**
* \class Derived
* \extends Base
*/

/**
* \memberof Base
* @{
*/

/**
* \brief Function A
*/
void Base_A();

/**
* \brief Function B
*/
void Base_B();

/** @} */
```

This creates page for derived class as following:

[image]

For some reason, there are two sections for inherited members - public inherited and related. In my opinion, both functions should be in the same category.

Adding \memberof command to every single function seems to solve the problem.

```
/**
* \class Base
*/

/**
* \class Derived
* \extends Base
*/

/**
* \brief Function A
* \memberof Base
*/
void Base_A();

/**
* \brief Function B
* \memberof Base
*/
void Base_B();
```

[image]

Can someone confirm this being a **bug**?

Can someone provide a working group assignment of multiple functions to a class? I have hundreds of functions and adding so many commands is not viable.

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to call this a bug. The `\{` `\}` commands are intended to be used for grouping together with grouping commands like \ingroup, \defgroup, \addtogroup, \weakgroup and in this case it is used together with \memberof.

It sees the `\memberof` command and 'assigns' the next function to 'Base' conform:

> This command makes a function a member of a class in a similar way as \relates does, only with this command the
>   function is represented as a real member of the class. This can be useful when the programming language does
>   not support the concept of member functions natively (e.g. C).

It looks like it ignores the `\{` and`\}`.

Comment: I have tried to remove the group operator `\{` and `\}`, but then the function Base_B is not connected to the base class at all. This means, that the operator is working.

Comment: It looks like it is working but the strange thing is that it places the functions in different categories (further functions are also landing in the "Related Functions inherited from Base" part. It has to be investigated what really happens, but I don't think that `\memberof ` was intended for this usage and that we see here a side effect.